# How to improve this query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got this query which I use in one of my PHP application:

```
SELECT DictSchemeName.schemeName, DictTableName.tableName 
FROM DictSchemeName, DictTableName 
WHERE DictSchemeName.Id = (SELECT  schemeName 
                           FROM ServiceSublayer 
                           WHERE sId = 3
                            AND ServiceId = (SELECT Id 
                                               FROM Service 
                                               WHERE applicationId = 'prga'))
  AND DictTableName.Id = (SELECT tableName
                          FROM ServiceSublayer
                          WHERE sId = 3 
                            AND ServiceId =(SELECT Id 
                                            FROM Service 
                                            WHERE applicationId = 'prga'));
```

as you can see I double almost the same query 2 times (DictSchemeName and DictTableName), I just start to learn SQL and I would be very glad if someone could help me.

I'm usng MS SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: You can use **`inner join`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to JOIN the tables:

```
select ds.schemeName,
  dt.tableName
from
(
  select schemeName, tableName
  from ServiceSublayer
  where sId = 3
    and ServiceId = (SELECT Id 
                     FROM Service 
                     WHERE applicationId = 'prga')
) s
inner join DictSchemeName ds
  on s.schemeName = ds.id
inner join DictTableName dt
  on s.tableName = dt.id;
```

Or even further:

```
select ds.schemeName,
  dt.tableName
from ServiceSublayer ss
inner join Service s
  on ss.serviceId = s.id
inner join DictSchemeName ds
  on ss.schemeName = ds.id
inner join DictTableName dt
  on ss.tableName = dt.id
where ss.sId = 3
 and s.applicationId = 'prga';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the option "Include Actual Execution Plan" as you analyze each of these queries.  With that you'll be able to see how you are actually improving each query. Here is one of many articles that show how to read the query plans, http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1630/how-to-use-a-sql-server-plan-guide-to-tune-queries/

As you follow along with how doing joins and avoiding subqueries and correlated subqueries affects your execution plans, you'll get a better underlying understanding of MSSQL and be able to code better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Break up your selects into individual statements...

```
DECLARE @ServiceId INT
DECLARE @schemeName VARCHAR
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR

SELECT @ServiceId = Id 
FROM Service
WHERE applicationId = 'prga'

SELECT @schemeName=schemeName,@tableName=tableName
FROM ServiceSublayer 
WHERE ServiceId = @ServiceId AND sId = 3

SELECT DictSchemeName.schemeName, DictTableName.tableName 
FROM DictSchemeName, DictTableName 
WHERE DictSchemeName.Id = @schemeName
AND DictTableName.Id = @tableName
```